# Can a sequence of functions converge to $0$ in only one $L_p$ space?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $1<p<\infty$, and suppose that $f_n$ converges to $0$ in the $L_q$ norm for all $q\neq p$ where $1\leq q<\infty$?  My question is, is it possible for $f_n$ to not converge to $0$ in the $L_p$ norm?

If there doesn't exist such a sequence of functions, does there at least a sequence of functions which does not converges to $0$ in some $L_p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ but converges to $0$ in every $L_q$ for $1<q<p$, and another sequence of functions which does not converge to $0$ in $L_p$ but converges to $0$ in every $L_q$ for $q>p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such sequence exists by Hölder's inequality. This is in Folland's book.

[image]

For the second question, you can do something analogous to what I did in my previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was hoping for something with $L_q$'s on both sides.  That is, I want $p$ to be greater than $1$ and to have the sequence converge for all $L_q$ where $q$ can be either less than or greater than $p$ (but still gretar than or equal to 1).  I'll modify my question to change greater than or equal to greater than.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan ok I changed my answer

Comment: OK, so there's no $L_p$ with $L_q$'s on both sides with the property I want.  But your previous answer at least addressed the case where it converges to $0$ in all $L_q$'s for $q>1$ but not for $L_1$.  But now what about the opposite case, a sequence of functions which converges to $0$ in all $L_q$'s $q$ between $1$ and $p$ (where $p$>1), but doesn't converge to $0$ in $L_p$?

Comment: $n1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ I think does the job

Comment: What is the $p$ it does the job for?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan sorry, $f_n := n^{1/2}1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ does the job for $p=2$. That is, $f_n \to 0$ in $L^q$ for $1 \le q < 2$ but $f_n \not \to 0$ in $L^2$.